# Unable to select data with d3.defer

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm stuck with a stupid problem in a D3 map. I load two files, and everything is fine, the colors are here, etc. However, I'm not able to adjust the opacity, because it takes the data in the json, not in the csv, for the if/else. Here is the sample of my code:

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "data/countries.json")
    .defer(d3.csv, "data/data.csv")
    .await(ready);

function ready(error, map, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var rateById = d3.map();

  var paths = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "countries")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(map, map.objects.countries).features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("opacity", function(d) { 
       var value = data.id;
       if (value) {
         return ".8";
       } else { 
         return ".1"; 
       }
     })

   // ...

});
```

Any idea how to aim correctly to the "id" column in data.csv? Thank you.

Comment: why do you say it does not get loaded...have you seen in chrome's network tab if  ajax call goes for data.csv?

Comment: Because the opacity is not adjusting to the formula. When I tried with d.id, it works well, but I don't know how to call the right function.

Comment: why are you doing `var value = data.id;` it should have been `var value = d.id;`

Comment: `d3.csv`'s callback is different with `d3.json`, check them out: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json, https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#csv

Comment: Thanks David, will check that.